# How to convert dd/mm/yy to yyyy-mm-dd in R

Tags: r

I have a vector with dates values in this format dd/mm/yy e.g.(27/06/16).
I want to convert this in this format yyyy-mm-dd e.g.(2016-06-27) for logical comparison. I am using this expression:

```
as.Date(as.character("27/06/16"), format = "%d")
```

and output comes out as:

```
"2016-07-27"
```

How can I convert this into required format.

Comment: `as.Date(as.character("27/06/16"), format = "%d/%m/%y")`

Comment: see `?strptime` for formats

Comment: @Sumedh Thanks it works.

Comment: @Vaibhav the output format you wanted is called **ISO 8601**, this will help you look for help about dates in the future.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)
dmy("27/06/16")
```

Answer (score 4):

With base **R**

```
as.Date(as.character("27/06/16"), format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to convert both date formats into a common POSIX representation:

```
d1 <- strptime("27/06/16", "%d/%m/%y")
d2 <- strptime("2016-06-27", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Since both `d1` and `d2` should be of the same R class, you can then just compare them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr

```
df.with.converted.date <- df.with.original.date %>%
  mutate(new.date.var = as.character(as.Date(old.date.var, "%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y%m%d"))
```

For example this will convert `"5/3/2019"` to `20190503`

Answer (score -2):

```
strDates <- c("27/06/16")
dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

this works.

refer this for more.http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Comment: this is basically the same as @J_F's answer, which he posted about 5 minutes earlier ....

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
as.Date( as.character("27/06/16"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```